# Can i use Entry repeatedly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

asp.net mvc 5, entity framework 6.0. I have ADO.NET EDM model. And i need update multiple entities. If i use Entry several times, i take exception: ObjectStateManager already have an object with the same key.
How i can do this, using something like this code:

```
db.Entry(company.Company).State = EntityState.Modified; //one type object
db.SaveChanges();
db.Entry(company.Preview).State = EntityState.Modified; //another type object
db.SaveChanges();

foreach (CompanyTelephone item in company.Phones) // another type
{
    if (item.Id > 0)
    {
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        db.CompanyTelephones.Add(item);
    }

}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Could it be that in your company.Phones collection you have multiple records with the same key? Also why are you calling SaveChanges so many times?

Comment: No. In Phones all keys is different. But id in phones and in Company or Preview may coincide, it causes an error.
For Savechanges: I thought it's reset ObjectStateManager, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Entry` as often as you want. The problem is in setting the state. If you set the state the `item` is attached to the context. Apparently, some items were already attached in the first two lines. You can simply check whether an `item` is `Detached`:

```
if (item.Id > 0 && db.Entry(item).State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
    db.CompanyTelephones.Add(item);
}
```

Still, as Andrei said, multiple `SaveChanges` calls should not be necessary. You break the transactional unit. Maybe it doesn't matter. Nevertheless, esp. the calls within the loop cause a lot of separate database rondtrips.